# Field not letting me type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I looked at some of the other approaches to resolve this, but couldn't figure this out. I'm using this [open source code](https://github.com/safak/youtube/blob/react-form/src/App.jsx) and trying to integrate it into mine. Seems very straight forward. This is what mine looks like.

```
const New = ({ inputs, title }) => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    firstName: "",lastName: "",email: "",password: "",confirmPassword: "",});
  const onChange = (e) => {setValues({ ...values, [e.target.id]: e.target.value })};
  const handleRegister = async (e) => {e.preventDefault()};

return (
<div className="new">
  <div className="newContainer">
    <Navbar />
    <div className="bottom">
      <div className="right">
        <form onSubmit={handleRegister}>
          {inputs.map((input) => (
            <div className="formInput" key={input.id}>
              <FormInput
                {...input}
                key={input.id}
                onChange={onChange}
                value={values[input.name]}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
          <button type="submit">Create Account</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: Using one big state variable in function components is not recommended, use several `useState()` hooks instead.

Comment: So create a useState for each of the 5 fields?

Comment: Are you sure `e.target.id` is what you think it is?

Comment: @Spider Yes, `const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState("")` and so on

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev you're right, it should be e.target.name!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it won't let you type, but if you look at the code I gave you, you might be able to apply it to your own code and get it to work. Other suggestions are also valid in the comments.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;
const App = () => {
  const inputs = [
    {
      id: "firstname",
      name: "firstname"
    },
    {
      id: "lastname",
      name: "lastname"
    },
    {
      id: "email",
      name: "email"
    },
    {
      id: "password",
      name: "password"
    },
    {
      id: "confirmpassword",
      name: "confirmpassword"
    }
  ];
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    firstname: "",
    lastname: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmpassword: ""
  });
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.id]: e.target.value });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(values);
  }, [values]);
  
  return (
    <div className="new">
      <div className="newContainer">
        <div className="bottom">
          <div className="right">
            <form>
              {inputs.map((input) => (
                <div className="formInput" key={input.id}>
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    {...input}
                    key={input.id}
                    onChange={onChange}
                    value={values[input.name]}
                  />
                </div>
              ))}
              <button type="submit">Create Account</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```